# Apache Redirect to two different servers bases on URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do the following:

I've a server A (`http://server-a:9000/`) and the server B (`http://server-b:8000/`). Additionally I've installed an Apache running on port 80.

When I access the apache with `http://localhost/product` I want to pass this request to `http://server-a:9000/product`

and

when I access the apache with `http://localhost/details` I want to pass the request to `http://server-b:8000/details`.

I'v got this working with the following configuration:

```
ProxyPass /product http://server-a:9000/product
ProxyPassReverse /product http://server-a:9000/product

ProxyPass /details http://server-b:8000/product
ProxyPassReverse /details http://server-b:8000/product
```

But with this configuration the original URL `http://localhost/product` is replaced by `http://server-a:9000/product`.

How can I configure my Apache so that it doesn't replace the URL? The displayed URL should always be `http://localhost/product`.

Thank you in advance

Torben

Comment: You could probably use a [frame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp) in your HTML page

Comment: Thank you Jwosty, but this didn't solve my problem

Comment: Okay, what else does it need to do?